# Linux Mint stuck at splash screen

Tags: boot, linux-mint

My problem is simple. I try to boot Linux mint 17 through grub (dual booted with win7), and it freezes at the mint logo splash screen.

I've read a couple things on this but the all suggest executing commands via a terminal. That isn't possible, as I can't get to a shell at all. All I get is a splash screen. Any ideas on how I can resolve this without reinstalling my entire OS?

Comment: Can you get a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F7?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but the issue seems to magically resolved itself after booting to a liveCD, doing nothing, and rebooting again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP indicates that this was a hiccup that corrected itself, so not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on a MSI GL72 laptop, resolved by setting the kernel option nomodeset.

- First, boot on a live system and update the file /etc/boot/grub.cfg on your system and change the lines :

  ```
  linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic root=*** ro  quiet splash  $vt_handoff
  ```

  To :

  ```
  linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic root=*** ro  quiet splash nomodeset $vt_handoff
  ```

  (change all the lines or just the first)
- Reboot without the live key.
- If it works, your change will be overrided by a grup-upgrade. To make they permanents :
- update file /etc/default/grub :

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
  ```
- Run the command update-grub to update the file /etc/boot/grub.cfg.

There are other options that was work for me (in addition of nomodeset) :

- acpi_osi=
- noidle

A useful post : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132.

for nomodeset : http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do.

Kernel parameters reference : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt.